# When is it dangerous to line break after a close parenthesis in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, line-breaks

- What are the dangers of breaking a line of long code up at a close parenthesis?
- When could a semicolon be automatically inserted by Javascript (presumably that is the danger, right?).
- Why is using a `)` as a line breaker "frowned upon" by JSLint?

In Javascript I sometimes see one long line of code broken up at a `)` like this (**[example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3721589/186636)**):

```
function ()
{
```

or like this (**[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713017/wait-for-ajax-call-post-to-finish/3713048#3713048)**):

```
object.methodOne()
      .methodTwo();
```

But when reading the **[line break expectations for jsLint](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html)**, it says:

> As a further defense against the semicolon insertion mechanism, JSLint expects long statements to be broken **only after one of these punctuation characters or operators**:

```
, ; : { } ( [ = < > ? ! + - * / % ~ ^ | &
== != <= >= += -= *= /= %= ^= |= &= << >> || &&
=== !== <<= >>= >>> >>>=
```

> JSLint does not expect to see a long statement broken after an identifier, a string, a number, closer, or a suffix operator:

```
. ) ] ++ --
```

So the close parenthesis is singled out as a line breaker that JSLint "doesn't expect to see."

I would prefer to use

```
function() 
{
```

since I find it more readable, and I already use it in other languages, but currently I use:

```
function () {
```

Could I safely use the `)` to break up long lines?

Comment: Note that jslint is purposely more defensive than the actual JS syntax, and it will complain about things that are valid Javascript (for instance, jslint considers `++` and `--` to be bad).

Comment: @Daniel - I understand that, but I assume that there are still reasons for the rules... I'm just not sure what they could be in the case of the close paren.

Comment: Although the function definition is 100% safe, there are other cases (see user166390's answer) where a `)` at the end could cause problems.

Comment: for clarity, I guess. Despite being valid, your second example could be misconstrued by a programmer who is reading it, or mistyped by a programmer who meant to specify a different object for the second method call.

Comment: You can use JsHint and chose which warnings you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This link should explain it all:

[JavaScript Semicolon Insertion](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons)

The "danger" is with (taken from the above link, emphasis added):

> > There are five restricted productions in the grammar, they are the postfix operators **++ and --**, **continue** statements, **break** statements, **return** statements, and **throw** statements.

`function()` is not in that "danger" list. However, when writing semi-colon free-code (I'm not sure if this is your aim :-), one should guard against lines starting with characters -- such as `(` or `[` -- that may start *or* continue an expression. The following code shows an example of code which is *likely* wrong:

```
x()
(function (){...})()
```

As you can see, *using `)` as a line-breaker may make the expression able to continue on subtly* without an explicit semi-colon **iff** the next line can continue the expression. I write the proceeding as (if the following is indeed the intent):

```
x()
;(function (){...})()
```

Personally, I dislike JSLint :-)
Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

When you're trying to return an object,

```
return {
 'foo': 'bar'
}
```

will return the object, whereas

```
return
{
  'foo': 'bar'
}
```

will return `undefined`. Javascript will automatically insert a semicolon after `return` in the second example, and the object will never be reached.

For functions, because `function()` isn't valid on its own, it shouldn't make a difference if the brace is on the same line or the next.

See also section [7.9.1 Rules of Automatic Semicolon Insertion](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) of the ECMAScript specification. Aside from `return`, there are four other situations where a semicolon will be inserted due to a newline: `break`, `continue`, `throw` and `++` or `--`.

> When a `continue`, `break`, `return`, or `throw` token is encountered and a *LineTerminator* is encountered before the next token, a semicolon is automatically inserted after the `continue`, `break`, `return`, or `throw` token.

Comment: So you're saying that a line break after `function ()` or `object.method()` could never insert a semi colon before the next continuing row?

Comment: For `function()`, JS shouldn't insert a semicolon. For `object.method()`, I don't believe it'll insert a semicolon if there is a newline before further chained method calls (from testing and experience), but I'm not 100% on what the spec is in this situation (because `object.method()` is valid syntax).

Comment: Thanks. In practice I've never had a problem with those sort of line breaks, but I'm always paranoid that there's some browser out there that won't interpret my code correctly because of it, or that there's some corner case I'll run into...

Answer (score 3):

A semicolon will be inserted only if the following line is not a valid continuation of the previous line (see exceptions below). So `function() {` with `{` on the next line is always safe.

From the ECMAScript spec:

> When, as the program is parsed from left to right, a token (called the offending token) is encountered that is not allowed by any production of the grammar,  then a semicolon is automatically inserted before the offending token if one or more of the following conditions is true:
>
> • The offending token is separated from the previous token by at least one LineTerminator.
>
> • The offending token is }.

Exceptions to this rule are the increment/decrement operators, `continue`, `break`, `return` and `throw`, whose arguments must always be on the same line:

> When a  ++ or  -- token is encountered where the parser would treat it as a postfix operator, and at least one LineTerminator occurred between the preceding token and the ++ or -- token, then a semicolon is automatically inserted before the ++ or -- token.
>
> When a continue, break, return, or throw token is encountered and a LineTerminator is encountered before the next token, a semicolon is automatically inserted after the continue, break, return, or throw token.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe.

I took a quick look at the semicolon insertion rules in the spec (3rd edition), and for function declarations it is OK.

Comment: Take a look at section 7.9.1. There are five situations where inserting a new line will cause a semicolon to be inserted where it is not desired.

Comment: I was referring to function declarations. function x() LINE_BREAK { is OK. Also true for function expressions.