# JS Strange behavior

Tags: javascript

Can someone assist me - why we have this behavior in JS snippet?

```
var foo = function() {
    return {
        hi: console.log("foo")
    }
}

var foo1 = function() {
    return 
    {
        hi: console.log("foo1")
    }
}

foo();
foo1();
```

Why only "foo" is printed?

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/apimenov93/gxysuxvc/)

**EDIT**
ok, this is because of automatic semi-colon insertion, BUT

do we have some ways to force JS to not execute this cases?

I mean, can we do something that will throw error here?

**EDIT2**

Looks like best suggestion is JShint - i asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987848/jshint-strange-behavior)

Comment: Just a hunch but could it be a timing thing? If you comment out `foo()` then `foo1` is printed. I do know that `console.log` some some strange thigns in the pipeline of logging if that makes sense.

Comment: Specifically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/3721802/476

Comment: @deceze then why does it run fine if `foo()` is commented out?

Comment: @ste2425 Say what now? Can you provide a fiddle for that statement/question?

Comment: @deceze yup https://jsfiddle.net/0gxw56xL/

Comment: @ste2425 You've moved the opening brace to be on the same line as `return`.

Comment: you reformated it, and that's the reason

Comment: Well aint that embarrassing, i never noticed sorry all, so used to clicking 'tidy'.

Comment: @ste2425 If you fix the exact issue that the question is about, well, yeah...

Comment: Your edit is quite a different question - you can use tools such as [jshint](http://jshint.com) (or jslint if you want to be really strict) - it will warn you about missing semicolons etc - paste your code above into that website to see.  There are various ways you can automate running it.

Comment: it is about to not allow running this, not get some warnings

Comment: You have to catch this at build time with a static analyser like jshint - you won't get it to throw errors, as it's technically valid code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've hit JavaScript's [automatic semi-colon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi).  Your second block is the equivalent of:

```
var foo1 = function(){
  return;
  {
    hi:console.log("foo1")
  }
}
```

IE it's not returning the object literal at all (and so the `console.log` isn't running) - it's just returning `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

In foo1, the function returns before the object is evaluated. If you check the output of `foo1()` it returns nothing This is why most javascript style guides suggest objects open on the same line as the `return` keyword.